# Docker Compose File Not Found es6-promise

Tags: c#, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I've got a "strange" error when executing "docker-compose up" (Docker for Windows + Windows Container).

```
Building [name of service] Traceback (most recent call last): File "docker-compose", line 6, in <module>
  File "compose\cli\main.py", line 71, in main
  File "compose\cli\main.py", line 127, in perform_command
  File "compose\cli\main.py", line 1052, in up
  File "compose\cli\main.py", line 1048, in up
  File "compose\project.py", line 466, in up
  File "compose\service.py", line 330, in ensure_image_exists
  File "compose\service.py", line 1027, in build
  File "site-packages\docker\api\build.py", line 154, in build
  File "site-packages\docker\utils\build.py", line 30, in tar
  File "site-packages\docker\utils\build.py", line 82, in exclude_paths
  File "site-packages\docker\utils\build.py", line 124, in walk
  File "site-packages\docker\utils\build.py", line 124, in <genexpr>
  File "site-packages\docker\utils\build.py", line 124, in walk
  File "site-packages\docker\utils\build.py", line 124, in <genexpr>
  File "site-packages\docker\utils\build.py", line 124, in walk
  File "site-packages\docker\utils\build.py", line 124, in <genexpr>
  File "site-packages\docker\utils\build.py", line 124, in walk
  File "site-packages\docker\utils\build.py", line 124, in <genexpr>
  File "site-packages\docker\utils\build.py", line 124, in walk
  File "site-packages\docker\utils\build.py", line 124, in <genexpr>
  File "site-packages\docker\utils\build.py", line 124, in walk
  File "site-packages\docker\utils\build.py", line 124, in <genexpr>
  File "site-packages\docker\utils\build.py", line 124, in walk
  File "site-packages\docker\utils\build.py", line 124, in <genexpr>
  File "site-packages\docker\utils\build.py", line 124, in walk
  File "site-packages\docker\utils\build.py", line 124, in <genexpr>
  File "site-packages\docker\utils\build.py", line 124, in walk
  File "site-packages\docker\utils\build.py", line 124, in <genexpr>
  File "site-packages\docker\utils\build.py", line 124, in walk
  File "site-packages\docker\utils\build.py", line 124, in <genexpr>
  File "site-packages\docker\utils\build.py", line 124, in walk
  File "site-packages\docker\utils\build.py", line 124, in <genexpr>
  File "site-packages\docker\utils\build.py", line 124, in walk
  File "site-packages\docker\utils\build.py", line 124, in <genexpr>
  File "site-packages\docker\utils\build.py", line 124, in walk
  File "site-packages\docker\utils\build.py", line 124, in <genexpr>
  File "site-packages\docker\utils\build.py", line 124, in walk
  File "site-packages\docker\utils\build.py", line 124, in <genexpr>
  File "site-packages\docker\utils\build.py", line 124, in walk
  File "site-packages\docker\utils\build.py", line 124, in <genexpr>
  File "site-packages\docker\utils\build.py", line 124, in walk
  File "site-packages\docker\utils\build.py", line 124, in <genexpr>
  File "site-packages\docker\utils\build.py", line 124, in walk
  File "site-packages\docker\utils\build.py", line 124, in <genexpr>
  File "site-packages\docker\utils\build.py", line 100, in walk
  FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht 
finden (translation: The system can't find the specified path): 'D:\\source\\[solution-folder]\\[project-folder]\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\npm-profile\\node_modules\\make-fetch-happen\\node_modules\\http-proxy-agent\\node_modules\\agent-base\\node_modules\\es6-promisify\\node_modules\\es6-promise\\lib\\es6-promise\\promise'
[9028] Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  [service-name]:
    image: [image name]
    build:
      context: [project folder]
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - sql.data
    ports: 
      - "12899:80"
  sql.data:
    image: microsoft/mssql-server-windows-express
    environment:
      sa_password: [very strong pwd]
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
    ports: 
      - "1433:1433"
```

Dockerfile

```
#escape=`
FROM [base_image] AS base
WORKDIR /dist
EXPOSE 80
COPY bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\publish\ .
USER ContainerAdministrator
RUN npm cache clean --force
RUN npm install
USER ContainerUser
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "[service].dll"]
```

Base Image (Dockerfile.inst):

```
#escape=`
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore:1709 as download

RUN @powershell New-Item -itemtype directory -path \"C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\"

# Retrieve and install .NET Core SDK
ENV DOTNET_SDK_VERSION 2.1.104
ENV DOTNET_SDK_DOWNLOAD_URL https://dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet/Sdk/$DOTNET_SDK_VERSION/dotnet-sdk-$DOTNET_SDK_VERSION-win-x64.zip
ENV DOTNET_SDK_DOWNLOAD_SHA f3a46570f220cafbdb2f7d40cddd09a8f718b62f02fbea79fdf8e48ac1871a20d2e79191b037a559b7f2bd88064e1ec70d2c68988312a7ee23d34dc757b9981b

RUN @powershell Invoke-WebRequest $Env:DOTNET_SDK_DOWNLOAD_URL -OutFile dotnet.zip; `
if ((Get-FileHash dotnet.zip -Algorithm sha512).Hash -ne $Env:DOTNET_SDK_DOWNLOAD_SHA) { `
    Write-Host 'CHECKSUM VERIFICATION FAILED!'; `
    exit 1; `
}; `
`
Expand-Archive dotnet.zip -DestinationPath \"C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\"; `
Remove-Item -Force dotnet.zip

FROM stefanscherer/node-windows:nanoserver AS base
RUN mkdir "C:\Program Files\dotnet"
COPY --from=download [ "C:/Program Files/dotnet", "C:/Program Files/dotnet" ]
RUN setx /M PATH "%PATH%;C:\Program Files\dotnet"
RUN setx /M PATH "%PATH%;C:\nodejs"
```

What I did:

1. Create Base Image "docker build -f Dockerfile.inst -t [base_image] ." (works)
2. Publish ASP .NET Core App (works: publish folder was created)
3. Build Dockerfile "docker build ." (works)
4. Run container "docker run [image-name]" (works)
5. "docker-compose up" -> results in the error

So I believe it has sth. to do with my docker-compose file? Maybe you guys got an idea!

Comment: Does it work if you remove the build statements in your docker-compose file so you rely fully on the manually built service image?

Comment: Yes it does. But why?

Comment: Your build process is too complicated, for me to figure that out. I think I would check the package.json (and package-lock.json if it's there) file to see if it looks good. My reason for checking there is that it looks like it's doing some npm stuff when it fails.

Comment: I tested some stuff and it seems to be the "npm install" in the dockerfile. It's strange because building the Dockerfile manually works. Is there a way to use "docker compose up" and seeing the output of docker build happening in the background? Edit: I actually realized I don't even need "npm install" because my application uses webpack. But nevertheless I would like to find out what's the problem.

Comment: I run Docker on Linux and if I use 'docker-compose up' without the '-d' switch, I can see everything in the console. Maybe Windows is different?

Comment: Have same issue. Maybe you found solution?